# Large mean squared error in sklearn regressors

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I'm a beginner in machine learning and I want to build a model to predict the price of houses. I prepared a dataset by crawling a local housing website and it consists 1000 samples and only 4 features (latitude, longitude, area and number of rooms).

I tried RandomForestRegressor and LinearSVR models in sklearn, but I can't train the model properly and the MSE is super high.

MSE almost equals 90,000,000 (the true values of prices' range are between 5,000,000 - 900,000,000)

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVR
import pandas as pd
import csv
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', index_col=False)
X = df.drop('price', axis=1)

X_data = X.values
Y_data = df.price.values
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X_data, Y_data, test_size=0.2, random_state=5)

rgr = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100)
svr = LinearSVR()

rgr.fit(X_train, Y_train)
svr.fit(X_train, Y_train)

MSEs = cross_val_score(estimator=rgr,
                         X=X_train,
                         y=Y_train,
                         scoring='mean_squared_error',
                         cv=5)

MSEsSVR = cross_val_score(estimator=svr,
                         X=X_train,
                         y=Y_train,
                         scoring='mean_squared_error',
                         cv=5)

MSEs *= -1
RMSEs = np.sqrt(MSEs)

print("Root mean squared error with 95% confidence interval:")
print("{:.3f} (+/- {:.3f})".format(RMSEs.mean(), RMSEs.std()*2))
print("")
```

Is the problem with my dataset and count of features? How can I build a prediction model with this type of dataset?

Comment: How's the MSE on the testing set?

Comment: I can upload and give the dataset, if it helps @Ding

Comment: It's almost 85,000,000 @Ding

Comment: Try changing your scoring parameter to `‘neg_mean_squared_error’`, as described [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter).  As a side note .. not seeing any linear regression here.  That and random forest regression are two very different beasts.

Comment: I changed the text of the question to `RandomForestRegressor`. It was a mistake.
With `neg_mean_squared_error` I get very similar result. Also when I try to `predict` a single sample, the result (price) is far from expecting price. @BradSolomon

Comment: @Saeed Have you tried to normalize/standardise the data ?